# Call a html file from a jsp

Tags: html, jsp, include-path

I wanted to call a html file index.html from a jsp file.
I have tried adding by the below two methods but it is not working.

```
<%@ include  file="C:\Users\vishal.tripathi\Desktop\bio-integration\bio-integration\verify\verify\index.html" %>
<c:import url="file:///C:/Users/vishal.tripathi/Desktop/bio-integration/bio-integration/verify/verify/index.html" />
```

Can anyone help me with the approach and the exact place in the jsp to add it.

Comment: omit the space between `@` and `include`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Tried that, doesn't work. Have added it in the start of jsp     <%@include  file="C:/Users/vishal.tripathi/Desktop/bio-integration/bio-integration/verify/verify/index.html" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to call html into jsp, you only need to change the path in url and I recommend you to use relative path.

```
 <c:import var="html" url="${file.name}.html" />
 <c:out value="${html}" escapeXml="false" />
```